# How to disconnect ONLY my browser from internet temporarily?

Tags: browser, youtube, upload, disconnect, resume

Is there a way I can disconnect ONLY my browser from internet temporarily so I can pause an upload for YouTube and the connect it again to resume it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I got it :3. If anyone wants to know...you go to the little 3 bars in the corner of the screen (chrome) > settings > scroll down to the text that says "Show advanced settings..." > click that > scroll down to the button that says "Change proxy settings..." > click that > click the tab that says "connections" > click "LAN settings" > click the box under "proxy server" that says "Use a proxy server for your LAN" > type in a random 11 digit number > click "OK".

You can change these settings back when ever you like just follow the steps again and un-check the box under "proxy server" that says "Use a proxy server for your LAN" > click "OK".

Hope this helped! :D

Comment: Isn't there a work-offline mode in chrome? There is one in Firefox.